# MYSQL Database column not updating

Tags: php, mysql

Please guys I need you help on updating mysql database. Below is the code:

```
$sql_1 = "UPDATE tbl_courier
          SET status = '$status', 
              comments = '$comments', 
              aarrival = '$aarrival', 
              transferdate = '$transferdate', 
              bl = '$bl', 
              `containerno` = '$containerno', 
              eta = '$eta', 
              rev_name = '$Receivername'
           WHERE cid = $cid
              AND cons_no = '$cons_no'";

  dbQuery($sql_1);
```

Every column updates with the new input except containerno, eta and rev_name

What have i done wrong please help...

Comment: Can you confirm $containerno, $eta and $rev_name have appropriate values?  Echo them out, or echo out the whole query.

Comment: You should probably be using a [prepared statement](http://us2.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).  It will really cut back on 1) errors like this and 2) SQL injection opportunities.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` if you're not already doing so.

Comment: I'm questioning the spelling of `aarrival` are you sure that column isn't named `arrival`? Plus, make sure the `cid` column is an `int` type. Also, GigaWatt mentioned in the now-deleted answer, about removing the backticks around the `containerno`. You should also make sure that your elements are indeed named with no typos, if this is coming from a form. You'll need to show a bit more code. As it stands, your question is unclear.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: $containerno in /home/masglobl/public_html/track/process.php on line 135

Notice: Undefined index: $eta in /home/masglobl/public_html/track/process.php on line 136

Notice: Undefined index: $Receivername in /home/masglobl/public_html/track/process.php on line 137

Notice: Undefined variable: Containerno in /home/masglobl/public_html/track/process.php on line 142

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/masglobl/public_html/track/process.php:135) in /home/masglobl/public_html/track/process.php on line 146

Comment: The Above is what I get now

Comment: There's your answer then. Look up those error messages and you'll end up fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there is one line out of place. Change this:

```
$sql_1 = "UPDATE tbl_courier
          SET status = '$status', 
              comments = '$comments', 
              aarrival = '$aarrival', 
              transferdate = '$transferdate', 
              bl = '$bl', 
              `containerno` = '$containerno', 
              eta = '$eta', 
              rev_name = '$Receivername'
           WHERE cid = $cid
              AND cons_no = '$cons_no'";

  dbQuery($sql_1);
```

To this:

```
$sql_1 = "UPDATE tbl_courier
          SET status = '$status', 
              comments = '$comments', 
              aarrival = '$aarrival', 
              transferdate = '$transferdate', 
              bl = '$bl', 
              containerno = '$containerno', 
              eta = '$eta', 
              rev_name = '$Receivername'
           WHERE cid = $cid
              AND cons_no = '$cons_no'";

  dbQuery($sql_1);
```

It's this line here:

```
`containerno` = '$containerno',
```

I believe you do not need the tilda before and after the column.

Old line:

```
`containerno` = '$containerno',
```

New line:

```
containerno = '$containerno',
```

When you add the tildas, as you can see. It is causing the rest of the syntax to nullify.

Comment: The error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); that Fre-ii gave was very helpful. I saw that my code was $containerno = $_POST['$containerno']; instead of  $containerno = $_POST['containerno'];